# Zip files only to be read by server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a themes management which is prebuilt HTML files for my CMS that I am writing. I have a folder called themes then inside that are the zip files for the themes. I have an unzip function that will add the theme to the public_html page for the site to work correctly. My issue is if I go to the url it will download the zip file, by adding an `.htaccess` to the themes folder should that protect that from people downloading the zip. Also another question, instead of downloading 300 zip folders, is there a another way to handle templates? Maybe on another website server which then will download to that users public_html.

For example:

You go to my cms site (kms.io [example]) they search for a theme and then they click add to site. It will automatically add it to their server. Or possibly inside the KMS CMS admin panel show the other servers files by iterating. Basically I'm wondering can I communicate between my server to their server so they can download templates that I provide for them.

I don't need a step by step tutorial or anything, just a basic concept that I can look into, or if there already is a tutorial out there a link as well. I've googled this and get some funny results that have nothing to do what I want. Reason for that is I'm not sure of what to call this action really.

**Refresher**

Instead of downloading the zips in the KMS package, can I communicate with a base server (my sites server) from another users server so they can download template packages that the KMS will offer. Almost like Wordpress I suppose, never used it to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

I could tell you about adding `basic authentication` in `htaccess` for the `themes` folder, or about using `mod-rewrite` to block access to the `zip` files...

But if you really don't want anyone to touch that folder, the one true-and-tried solution (also recommended for your code) is this:

**Move the folder above the web root.**

You can still access it in your code, but the rest of the world won't be able to touch it.

Regarding storage, there are many ways to approach it. There is nothing to keep you for instance from storing the zip files as blobs in a database (on your server or a different one) that users can search.

Comment: +1 for above web root, I like keeping all my code above the web accessible location and only expose an index.php file.

Comment: See I've never used Blob, so I'd have to some reading on that. And moving it is a good idea for sure. But it would be on my own server so that the KMS users who download the source to upload to their source never have to download 300 zips. So how would I go about the authentication so I can access the users server, now I am not trying to access anything specifically I just want them to be able to download the zip (which my unzip function extracts the files) so they can have the template they want without jamming their server.

Comment: `blob` stands for Binary Large Object, it's one of the available field types in the MySQL database, frequently used with PHP. The user has no idea you're talking to a database, whether on your server or another. If that sounds like a worthwhile option to investigate, find a quick tut about PHP + MySQL. :)

Comment: Ok sounds good to me, I'll search for blob tuts. But will need to search communication between two servers as well.